# What is the best way to add a pivot table sheet in excel using Talend Job?

Tags: excel, etl, talend, excel-2016

I am developing a **Talend Automation Job**,
where I need to fetch my data in a "*data*" sheet in Excel.
And then add a summary using Pivot table in excel in a separate sheet "*Segment_Summary*" 
in same excel workbook.
(using Excel 2016)
Then send it in *tsendMail* to clients as attachment.
Can you tell me a better way than what I did as explained below?

## So,  here is what I tried doing:

I created a sample Workbook with "*data*" sheet . 
Selected cells of "*data*" sheet and created a named range for them. 
Then added a pivot table on that named range in new sheet "*Segment_Summary*".
Also set my Pivot Settings to Automatically Refresh whenever File gets opened.
Inside Talend , I fetch my data into a new excel file using *tFileOutputExcel*.
Copy *Segment_Summary* sheet from my Sample Workbook into this new excel file using *tFileCopy*.
Using *tsendMail* sent the excel as attachment

## What happened to the output :

Executed my job, 
checked the new Excel created.
Its good,
pivot is *automatically refreshed* to new data .

## So what goes wrong here:

When I download the file *from mail* and then open it, pivot is not refreshed.
This is because by default MS Excel opens every file in **Protected Mode** and disables Editing.
So, when clients will open this file, they will see outdated data instead of refreshed one.

*(I cannot simply write in mail that open it in editing mode, as this has to be sent to many people..and my email template is word-to-word decided by sales.)*

Answer (score 0):

doesn't tFileCopy copy files? How are you using this to copy a single sheet from an Excel file?

Given that Talend doesn't "understand" Excel - only data and files - the only approach I can think of that might work is to have your target Excel file already containing the pivot table and then use Talend to update the sheet in that target file that contains the raw data.

I'd probably create a template Excel file with example data and a pivot table and then in each run create a copy of this file and update the copy.

Given that the size of the raw data is likely to change from run to run, you're probably also going to have issues with the named range that the pivot table is using - assuming the named range is fixed. Having a dynamic named range may be needed, this link explains how to implement this, if you need to know: [Dynamic Named Range](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html)

Comment: Rest assured, I did read your entire post. To be able to help you I need to understand why Excel is not acting as I expect it to; therefore I need to understand how you are constructing the workbook with Talend. One of the statements you made about this process, "Copy Segment_Summary sheet from my Sample Workbook into this new excel file using tFileCopy." is not possible as far as I am aware - so either there is a way of using this functionality that I am not aware of, in which case I'd like to learn from your superior knowledge, or you've incorrectly described your process or your results

Comment: ok leave aside what i did, i might have not correctly explained my process. But as i mentioned in "What happened to output"  i was able to automatically refresh my pivot , only thing that went wrong is when someone else will open this output file, it will open in read-only mode and in this mode pivot will not be auto-refresh.

Comment: and same will be the case in your solution also, if i am not wrong.

Comment: I've been trying various solutions and, unfortunately, I do not believe it is possible to achieve what you want. It is not possible to refresh a pivot table (or, as far as I can tell from my research, anything else) without physically opening the Excel file - and that is not possible within Talend; if you could open and close the file before you emailed it then it would be sent in the refreshed state

Comment: The only way this might work is if you called a system process to open the Excel file and another process to close it (using tSystem components). However, you'd need to be able to get the PID of the Excel running process in order to be able to close it plus you'd also need all the required access permissions to run these commands - so the get this working would be highly dependent on your environment and is, unfortunately, beyond my Windows/Unix scripting abilities

Comment: its ok. for now i will go with first solution only. Thanks a lot